# Can we have two or more container running on docker at the same time

Tags: docker, containers, microservices

I have not done any practical with the docker and container, But as per my knowledge.

As per the documents available online I did not get the details about the running two or more containers at the same time.

Docker allows container to map port address of container to the host machine.
Now, the question is can we run multiple container at the same time on docker? if yes then if two containers are mapped to same port number then how does the port is handled in this case?

Also out of curiosity, can two containers on docker communicate with each other?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can run multiple containers on a single host; docker is designed for exactly that.

You cannot map two containers of different images to the same port number; you get an error response if you try. However, if your containers run the same image (e.g.2 instances of a webapp) you could run them as a service, and have them exposed on the same port. Docker will load-balance the requests. You can read more about [services here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/services/) or follow the [Get Started (Part 3, services) here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/)

Yes, the containers on a single host can communicate with each other, by container name. For example if you have one container running MongoDB called *mongo*, and another one running Node.js called webserver, the webserver container can connect to the database by using the name *mongo* e.g. `db.Connect("mongodb://mongo:27017/testdb")`.

Answer (score 2):

We can run more one than one Docker at a time in a host but yes we will hit the limitation of binding the same port to the docker; so to resolve this we need to bind different port in the host to docker that is if you are running mongo-db then its default port is 27017 so we can run two mongo-db as -p 27017:27017 for Docker D1 and -p 27018:27017 for Docker D2 and 5000:27017 for docker D3; Like this you can bind different host port to map to 27017 for mongo-db port; Now your question is how to manage this ports from host then I would recommend you to use nginx for port managing in the host machine.

Coming to your next question all dockers are connected to default docker0 bridge network so we can connect to any of the dockers connected to default bridge 'docker0' network; If I am right  it will come with ipaddress of 172.x.x.x network. Get inside to the docker and run 'ip addr' to see the ip-address assigned to the dockers and you can test connection by running ping command.

Comment: I am trying this with ghost and I can't connect to the second instance which is mapped to a different host port.

Answer (score 0):

Yes two containers can run same time, they can also communicate with each other also, you can define your own network and they can communicate with each other. if two containers have their private ports, they are their internal ports, one container port does not collide with another container port. if you want to expose the port to host, then you have to publish the port(s).